# How to create a variable from a array with all values into ihe variable separated by 'comma'?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I Have to iterate through an array, such that I can get all values of the array inside my desired variable in csv format?

My basic aim is to insert these csv values in to a column of db table.

Please guide to acheive this..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use '[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)' in combination with a function dependant on your array structure.

i.e. `implode(",", $array);`

eg:

```
$array=array("value1", "value2", "value3");
echo implode(",",$array);
```

Would give you:

> value1,value2, value3

Ideally your dataset will look like this:

```
$arrayofdata[rownumber][fieldnumber];
```

So rownumber 1 would have fieldnumber (or name) 1, 2, 3 etc..

You would then do:

```
// Loop through each row
foreach ($arrayofdata as $key){
    echo implode(",", $arrayofdata[$key])."\r";
    // joining each field with a comma, then moving onto a new line
}
```